# How to compare a string array within dictionary key

Tags: c#, winforms

I created dictionary like this:

`Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();`

And I had a string array like this:

`string[] str = new string[]{"str1","str2","str3"}`

Now I want to check if `dic` key contains all elements of `str` without using loop. What is the best way to do this?. Thanks.

Comment: _"without using loop"_ not possible, even LINQ uses loops. Also, that's a `Dictionary[]`, do you want to know if one dictionary contains all keys, if all dictionaries contain all keys or if all dictionaries contain all keys but in total(f.e. the first contains `str1`, the second `str2` etc)?

Comment: the accepted answer does'n compile since a Dictionary is'n a nested List

Comment: @Byyo TimSchmelter was correct, OP changed the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if all dictionaries contain all keys:

```
bool allContainsAll = dic.All(dictonary => str.All(dictonary.ContainsKey));
```

If you want to know if the strings are in any of the dictionaries keys:

```
var allDictKeys = new HashSet<string>(dic.SelectMany(d => d.Keys));
bool allContainsAll = str.All(allDictKeys.Contains);
```

Note that LINQ also uses loops, you just don't see them.

Comment: What is the 'd' and 's' ??

Comment: @AJHope: that's a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). The `d` and `s` are variables for the projected objects. In this case dictionaries and strings. I've renamed the dictionary variable and removed the `s` since you can pass the method directly in this case.

Answer (score 5):

this is a solution with linq, at least no visible loops, but internal linq uses loops

```
Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dic.Add("str1", 1);
dic.Add("str2", 2);
dic.Add("str3", 3);

string[] str = new string[] { "str1", "str2", "str3" };
bool ContainsAll = str.All(dic.ContainsKey); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare a dictionary and a string array you can use SequenceEqual:

```
bool AreEqual = dic.Keys.SequenceEquals(str);
```

or if they are not in the same sequence:

```
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(dic.Keys); 
bool AreEqual = set.SetEquals(str);
```